# Python equivalent of Curl HTTP post

Tags: python, http, curl

I am posting to Hudson server using curl from the command line using the following--

```
curl -X POST -d '<run><log encoding="hexBinary">4142430A</log><result>0</result><duration>2000</duration></run>' \
http://user:pass@myhost/hudson/job/_jobName_/postBuildResult
```

as shown in the hudson documentation..can I emulate the same thing using python..i don't want to use pyCurl or send this line through os.system()..is there ny way out using raw python??

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990976/convert-a-curl-post-request-to-python-only-using-standard-libary

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
result = response.read()
```

where data is the encoded data you want to POST.

You can encode a dict using urllib like this:

```
import urllib

values = { 'foo': 'bar' }
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
```

Comment: Sweet and simple, thank you! However, to encode data I had to use `urllib.urlencode` as `encode` was not found.

Comment: I would recommend the requests module for making HTTP requests (see Ashish Gulati's answer). The library automatically handles things like urlencoding and such so you can focus on more important things.

Answer (score 21):

The modern day solution to this is much simpler with the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) module (tagline: *HTTP for humans!* :)

```
import requests

r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'}, auth=('user', 'passwd'))
r.text      # response as a string
r.content   # response as a byte string
            #     gzip and deflate transfer-encodings automatically decoded 
r.json()    # return python object from json! this is what you probably want!
```

Comment: The requests module is truly a work of art and the right tool for the job. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This response was the best for my problem. Thanks