# Converting cURL to Python: With extra parameters

Tags: python, curl

I am trying to make API requests with **proper authorization**. I looked at [Conversion of curl to python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461194/conversion-of-curl-to-python-requests) but am having trouble putting the authorization headers.

This is what I have so far:

```
import base64
import http.client
import requests
import json

headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode(b'username:password').decode('ascii'),
    }
payload = {json.dumps({"one":["two:three:four"]})}
url = 'https://website/v1'


r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

if __name__=='__main__':
    print (r.text)
```

The only difference between the link provided above and my code is that he has `query={"tags":["test1","test2"]}` I do not have that at all.

This is the curl I am trying to translate to get what I got above.

```
curl -X POST -u "username:password" -H "Content-Type:application/json" "https://website.com" -d '{"ids":["something:numberOne:numbertwo"]}'
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Don't convert the payload to a string, leave it as a python object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246021/python-equivalent-of-curl-http-post

Comment: My apologies, but could you clarify?