# Execute curl command and fetch response

Tags: python, curl, libcurl, pycurl

I have a curl command. I want to fetch the response after executing it in python 3.

```
curl https://api.abc.com/targets/targetID\ 
-X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: JWT PROBELY_AUTH_TOKEN"
```

How can I execute the script in Python and get the response ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python equivalent of Curl HTTP post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246021/python-equivalent-of-curl-http-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.abc.com/targets/AxthamE0v3E-/scans/S6dOMPj8SsoH/'
r = requests.get(url,headers={"Content-Type": "application/json","Authorization": "JWT PROBELY_AUTH_TOKEN"})
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform a request, you can use the library `requests`.
You can easily install it with `pip install requests`

https://www.w3schools.com/python/module_requests.asp
You can use this link to see how to work with this library