# Translating curl to python urllib2

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, libcurl, urllib

Can someone please show me how to convert this curl call into call using python urllib2

```
curl -X POST
-H "Content-Type:application/json"
-d "{\"data\":{}}"
-H "Authorization: GoogleLogin
auth=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789...XYZ"
https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1/training?data=${mybucket}%2F${mydata}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990976/convert-a-curl-post-request-to-python-only-using-standard-libary

Comment: Also, Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: It might be easier to convert the curl command using pycurl or mechanize, rather than only urllib2. Is that an option for you?

Comment: i figured it out, and plan on posting to code monentarily

Answer (score 1):

Found it here:

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/06/Trying-out-the-new-Prediction-API