# Creating a nested JSON request with Python

Tags: python, json, serialization, curl, deserialization

A user needs to pass a json object as a part of the request.  It would look something like this:

```
   {"token" :"ayaljltja",
   "addresses": [
      {'name':'Home','address':'20 Main Street', 
       'city':'new-york'}, 
      {'name':'work', 'address':'x Street', 'city':'ohio'}
   ]}
```

I have two problems right now. First, I can't figure out how to test this code by recreating the nested POST.  I can successfully POST a dict but posting the list of addresses within the JSON object is messing me up.

Simply using cURL, how might I do this?  How might I do it with urrlib2?

My second issue is then deserializing the JSON POST object on the server side. I guess I just need to see a successful POST to determine the input (and then deserialize it with the json module).

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure your JSON is valid.  Paste it into the [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) web page.

Currently your JSON has two issues:

1. there is no comma between `"token" :"ayaljltja"` and `"addresses": [...]`
2. a single quote is not a valid way of delimiting a JSON string, replace them all with double quotes.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, thanks.  My json is actually valid in real life. Just a typo in SO.  When I look at the Request Object, the issue is that the  "addresses" object looks like the following: [u"{'city': 'new-york', 'name': 'Home', 'display_value': '2 Main Street'}", u"{'city': 'new-york', 'name': 'Home', 'display_value': '2 Main Street'}"].  I don't know why i'm getting unicode objects in my list. When I try to serialize those objects, the serializer fails (because of the single quotes, I believe).

Answer (score 2):

With command line curl, save your JSON to a file, say data.json. Then try: `curl -X POST -d @data.json http://your.service.url`

It's also possible to enter the JSON directly to the -d parameter but (as it sounds like you know already) you have to get your quoting and escaping exactly correct.

Comment: Hey Ian, I was afraid of something like that.  Quoting/escaping is a pain that I'm aware of here.  Any thoughts on using urllib2 or urllib to save me from some of this annoyance? I couldn't figure it out with urlencode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348061/how-to-use-python-urllib2-to-send-json-data-for-login/7469725#7469725b looks like it covers what you're trying to do.