# POST request in Python returns urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, zendesk

I am trying to create new organizations in Zendesk using their Core API. I have been able to make other calls without issue but this one continues to fail. The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
url = "https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations.json"
new_org = {"organization": {"name": "new organization"}}
data = urllib.urlencode(new_org)
req = urllib2.Request(url,data)
password_manager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_manager.add_password(None, url, 'me@email.com', 'fakepassword')
auth_manager = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_manager)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
bla = response.read()
```

The following error occurs:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/network/nfshome0/homestore00/me/workspace/Pythony/pythony/test2.py", line   35, in <module>
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 890, in http_error_401
    url, req, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 865, in http_error_auth_reqed
    response = self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 878, in retry_http_basic_auth
    return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Using the following helped:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348061/how-to-use-python-urllib2-to-send-json-data-for-login

Answer (score 0):

Your problem relates to the use of `urllib.urlencode`. As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) indicates this will:

> Convert a mapping object or a sequence of two-element tuples to a “percent-encoded” string.

The [Zendesk Organizations API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/organizations) expects to receive JSON data as the body of the request. Zendesk cannot understand your request as it is in the wrong format. The 400 status code that was returned indicates this. The [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) on status codes describes a 400 status code as:

> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., **malformed request syntax**, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Now while you could fix this by correctly including the data in the request like this:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, json.dumps(new_org))
```

You would really save yourself a lot of effort if you used the [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library. I do not have access to Zendesk to test this but I suspect that your code could be rewritten as:

```
import requests

new_org = {"organization": {"name": "new organization"}}
response = requests.post(
    "https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations.json",
    auth=('me@email.com', 'fakepassword'),
    data=new_org
)
data = response.json()
```