# Python Urllib2 Post Data Request Formatting

Tags: python, formatting, urllib2

Normally a request would be formatted in Python as:

```
varName = {'username': 'password'}
```

The normal request would be:

```
username=password
```

My problem is the request that I am trying to send is:

```
{"part1":"part2"}
```

I don't know how to format this for `python`. I simply need assistance with formatting it. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? A little bit of research on internet may give you the answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use python urllib2 to send json data for login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348061/how-to-use-python-urllib2-to-send-json-data-for-login)