# Exception Value: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request after a Python/urllib2 request to PayPal Sandbox Site

Tags: python, curl, paypal

I'm trying to integrate PayPal REST API in my website. As a first step, I'm trying to translate cURL commands into Python and I'm getting an `Exception Value: HTTP Error 400`.

The code I'm using (is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003832/2675537):

```
def basic_authorization(user, password):
    s = user + ":" + password
    return "Basic " + s.encode("base64").rstrip()

req = urllib2.Request("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
              headers = {
   "Authorization": basic_authorization("EBWKjlELKMYqRNQ6sYvFo64FtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM", "EO422dn3gQLgDbuwqTjzrFgFtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM"),
 "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept": "*/*",   
    "User-Agent": "my-python-app/1", 
    },
                  data = '{"message":{"body":' + 'grant_type=client_credentials' + '}}' )

f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
return HttpResponse(f)
```

which is the equivalent (I guess) to:

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-u "EBWKjlELKMYqRNQ6sYvFo64FtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM:EO422dn3gQLgDbuwqTjzrFgFtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

And the traceback is here: (**Edit**: Broken Link)

[According to PayPal](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/curl?interactive=ON&env=sandbox) I should get a response like this:

```
{"scope":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/developer/.*","access_token":"OABI8rm75u.5EIuK7.JrI2sLhnv3rhDgLElKAwTfyys","token_type":"Bearer","app_id":"APP-2EJ531395M785864S","expires_in":28800}
```

Is there an error in my code? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I would suggest using the excellent [requests library](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), this does not directly solve your issue but it makes easier/cleaner code. Btw, most Rest-APIs return a body on Status-Code 400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you not to post your keys in clear text in your code examples.

The error your getting  "HTTP Error 400: Bad Request", is due to a badly formed request.

From the docs the format for a request is:

urllib2.Request(url[, data][, headers][, origin_req_host][, unverifiable])

> data may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server,
>   or None if no such data is needed.
>
> headers should be a dictionary, and will be treated as if add_header()
>   was called with each key and value as arguments.

So your data field is passing a dict instead of string, and it would be a lot more readable
if you separated the fields outside of the Request class. When you have multiple header 
fields to fill in, I find it better to use the add_header method as shown below.

```
import urllib, urllib2


def basic_authorization(user, password):
    s = user + ":" + password
    return "Basic " + s.encode("base64").rstrip()

url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
params = { "grant_type": client_credentials}
data = urllib.urlencode(params)

req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
req.add_header("Authorization",basic_authorization("XXX"))
req.add_header("Accept", "application/json")
req.add_header("User-Agent", "my-python-app/1")

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```